# Modules and legacy Fortran 77 codes

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have set of blas/lapack functions that I got from NETLIB website. I would like to put these functions inside a Fortran module. The rest of my code is in Fortran 90. So I go about doing this:

```
module modname
contains


double precision function ddot(n,dx,incx,dy,incy)
.
.
.
end function 


subroutine dpofa(a,lda,n,info) 
.
.
        double precision ddot
.
end subroutine dopfa
end module
```

When I compile using

```
gfortran modname.f90
```

I get the following error:

> /tmp/ccC2EUFj.o: In function `__temp_MOD_dpofa':
>   temp.f90:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to`ddot_'

I am ignoring the error about `Undefined reference to main`, I realize it happens because I do not have program .. end program statements in the file.

If, however, I remove the lines with `module modname`, `contains` and `end module` the compiler compiles without any issues.

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: You need to tell gfortran to link against the math libraries, e.g.: `-llapack -lblas`

Comment: I have the source code itself in the module. I do not understand why I need to link with lapack/blas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your non-module approach you have lots of external functions and subroutines.  That is, if these are defined outside the module then one procedure has no clue about another.  You tell the subroutine `dpofa` about the function `ddot` by using the declaration statement `double precision ddot`.  The compiler mangles that name to `ddot_` (see elsewhere for details of that) and also mangles the name of the real function you have to the same.  The linker resolves one symbol to the other when needed.

When you come to using a module, you still have this external function declaration, but now the real function you have, in the same module, is no longer external.  Instead, there is a module procedure which gets mangled to something like `__temp_MOD_ddot`.  You aren't creating a function with the mangled name `ddot_` any longer.

You presumably have a reference to the function `ddot` in `dpofa`, but in the module version that will be to the symbol `ddot_` which isn't defined.

You'll want to remove the function declarations for those functions which are now defined in the same module, and are no longer external.